# CSS :after content below a select element causes click not to work

Tags: css, select, absolute, pseudo-element

I have this (simplified) css for the select element to get rid of the browser-specific appearance

```
.select{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
.select:after{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;right:0;
    content:'\2193'; 
}
select{
    appearance:none; (-moz and -webkit too)
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

(Best seen in http://jsfiddle.net/kwpke3xh/)

```css
body{
    background:#eef;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
.select{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-radius:.5em;
    border:.1rem solid #000;
    color:#013;
    width:8em;
    height:1.5em;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:relative;
}
.select:after{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:.15em;top:.15em;right:.5rem;
 content:'\2193'; 
}
select{
    -webkit-appearance:none;
   -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    font:inherit;
    border:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    color:inherit;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<span class="select">
    <select>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

It looks good, aside from Firefox still showing the arrow (as described [Firefox 30.0 - -moz-appearance: none not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24165355/firefox-30-0-moz-appearance-none-not-working))

The only technical problem is that when I click on the select element, it shows the option elements, but if I click directly on the arrow, it does not.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The simplest CSS solution would be to add [**`pointer-events: none`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to the pseudo element. In doing so, you can click through the element because mouse events are removed.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qnpLrffh/)

```
.select:after {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:.15em;
    top:.15em;
    right:.5rem;
    content:'\2193';
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

<sup>(Just take [browser support for the property](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) into consideration.)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! Learned something new today.